# Name for set of all sequences using one element from input sequences at each index

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I am given $m$ sequences of length $n$. Is there a term for the $m^n$ sequences that can be formed by taking one element at index $i$ from any of the original sequences?  Or perhaps a term for the process of constructing such a set?

For example, given two source sequences, $\langle 1,2,3 \rangle$ and $\langle 10, 20, 30 \rangle$, the resulting sequences would be:

$$\langle 1, 2, 3\rangle , \langle 1, 2, 30\rangle , \langle 1, 20,
3\rangle , \langle 1, 20, 30\rangle , \langle 10, 2, 3\rangle , \langle
10, 2, 30\rangle , \langle 10, 20, 3\rangle , \langle 10, 20, 30\rangle$$

It seems like such a term would come from combinatorics.  The only terms I know that are kind of in the same ballpark are "permutation" and "combination".  fwiw I have looked at some combinatorics pages on the web, but haven't noticed anything promising yet.  e.g. I've looked at every definition containing "sequence" at Douglas B. West's [Glossary of Terms in Combinatorics](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~dwest/openp/gloss.html).  Maybe I'm just not noticing some other way of thinking about these sequences that would lead me to an obvious term.

EDIT: Here is more concrete way of illustrating the kind of sequence-construction relation that I have in mind:

I have $n$ "target" bins in a row that I'm trying to fill with one marble each.  I have $m$ other rows of "source" bins of the same length.  Each source bin contains a single, unique marble.  To fill target bin $i$, I can use a single marble from the $i$th bin in any one of the source rows.  I can't use the same marble twice.

(The uniqueness of marbles is just a way of capturing the idea that the combination of an index $i$ and a source row specifies a unique filler of a target bin at $i$.  In practice the marbles could have numbers on them, and there's nothing in the story that implies that two bins couldn't have the same marble-number in them if, for example, source row $k$ has the number 14 on the marble in bin 22, while source row $k'$ has a 14 on the marble in bin 25, or in 22 as well.  That is, any number could be in any position in the source sequences, but I can only fill target sequence location $i$ from location $i$ in some source sequence.)

Comment: Looks a bit like what you do when you take the determinant? ($A_{i,\sigma(i)}$ in Liebniz formula, row i being analogous to the index here ... maybe). Maybe you can find something in algebra.

Comment: I see the analogy, @Emil.  Will think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct them, you can form all the words of length $n$ out of the characters $\{1,2,3,\ldots,m\}$  The character at position $k$ tells you which sequence to take the $k^{\text{th}}$ character of.  There are $m^n$ of them in the set.  It feels a bit like a Cartesian product of the sequences, but I don't know a nice name for the set.

Comment: Nice representation.  Hmm ... so let the $m$ sequences be row vectors, and stack them up as rows of an $m\times n$ matrix.  Then we can think of the target sequences as the Cartesian product of elements of the column vectors.  I'm thinking about this.  (The matrix just provides a convenient way of expressing the transformation.)

Answer (score 0):

Set of all permutations with repetitions.

Resulting sequence $i$-th element is formed using $i$-th element from $j$-th given sequence, so that $j_i$ can be equal $j_{i+1}$. This means that repetitions are allowed. See [wiki].[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)

Imagine, that you have no $m$ sequences of length $n$, but you have set of $m$ elements. You construct a resulting sequence of length $n$, so that elements in sequence can be included more than one time.

Comment: Thanks P.M.Z.  But either I'm misunderstanding you, or you've misunderstood me. Either way, it may be my fault. I had trouble making the idea as clear as I'd wanted.  Think of it this way: I have $n$ "target" bins in a row that I'm trying to fill with one marble each.  I have $m$ other rows of "source" bins of the same length.  Each source bin contains a single, unique marble.  To fill target bin $i$, I can use a single marble from the $i$th bin in any one of the source rows.  I can't use the same marble twice. Does that fit your understanding of what I was asking about?  Thanks.